# Best way to show a field that queries data from other object based on field selections?

Tags: formula, query, object, product, sales

Use case is: I have products that have different prices from different suppliers. Maintaining several pricebooks is too complicated and we would need multiple pricebooks for Opty and orders. So we created a custom object named supplierprice with a lookup to product and supplier (type of account) and the price field.

Now I need from line item selections to show a field that shows the price based on the product and line item selection. After insert/update triggers will show it once it is inserted, I need to show it before, while user is entering quantity.

Is there a way to show a formula field or similar, that queries data based on selection changes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  The record must be saved in order to see new formula values in the UI.  You could code a custom order entry component in order to dynamically show new values based on selection.